# HTML form returns nothing on Firefox&IE (ok on Chrome)

Tags: html, internet-explorer, firefox, jinja2

I have this form in my HTML:

```
<form action="/vcontent?topic={{ topic.name }}" method="post">
  {% if user and user.email in c.users_up %}
    <input type="image" src="icons/thumb-up.png" alt="Up!" name = "vote" value = "up" />
  {% else %}
    <input type="image" src="icons/thumb-up_gray.png" alt="Up!" name = "vote" value = "up" />
  {% endif %}
  {% if user and user.email in c.users_down %}
    &nbsp;<input type="image" src="icons/thumb-down.png" alt="Down!" name = "vote" value = "down" />
  {% else %}
    &nbsp;<input type="image" src="icons/thumb-down_gray.png" alt="Down!" name = "vote" value = "down" />
  {% endif %}
  <input name= "content_key" type="hidden" value="{{ c.key.urlsafe() }}">
</form>
```

When I try to upvote a content on Chrome, it works fine. When I get the value with:

```
vote = self.request.get('vote')
```

I get either "up" or "down", as it's supposed to be.

But when i do the same thing on IE and Firefox i get an empty string as a result.

(The if/else statements in the HTML mean that if the user has not yet voted that specific content the icon shows up gray, otherwise it's black).

I'm working on Google App Engine using Jinja2 as a template engine.

Comment: You are aware that `<input type="image"` will submit the form?

Comment: Yes, it works like that. It's an icon that submits the form when pressed. But it should be with either vote = "up" or vote = "down", not with vote = "".

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Instead of using an image, use a button:

```
<style>button {height:32px; width:32px;}</style>

<form action="/vcontent?topic={{ topic.name }}" method="post">
  {% if user and user.email in c.users_up %}
     <button type="submit" style="background: url(icons/thumb-up.png)" title="Up!" name="vote" value="up" />
  {% else %}
     <button type="submit" style="background: url(icons/thumb-up_gray.png)" title="Up!" name="vote" value="up" />
  {% endif %}
  {% if user and user.email in c.users_down %}
    &nbsp;<button type="submit" style="background: url(icons/thumb-down.png)" title="Down!" name="vote" value="down" />
  {% else %}
    &nbsp;<button type="submit" style="background: url(icons/thumb-down_gray.png)" title="Down!" name="vote" value="down" />
  {% endif %}
  <input name= "content_key" type="hidden" value="{{ c.key.urlsafe() }}">
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks! that works, but messes up badly the icons on the page, i tried to resize them with some CSS but it didn't work.
Isn't there any way to make it work with images instead of buttons?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I think I worked it out, I'm posting my solution for whoever might want to do this, that's the code:

```
<form action="/vcontent?topic={{ topic.name }}" method="post">
  {% if user and user.email in c.users_up %}
    <input type="image" src="icons/thumb-up.png" alt="Up!" name = "vote" value = "up" />
  {% else %}
    <input type="image" src="icons/thumb-up_gray.png" alt="Up!" name = "vote" value = "up" />
  {% endif %}
  <input type="hidden" name = "vote" value = "up"/>
  <input name= "content_key" type="hidden" value="{{ c.key.urlsafe() }}">
</form>
<form action="/vcontent?topic={{ topic.name }}" method="post">
  {% if user and user.email in c.users_down %}
    &nbsp;<input type="image" src="icons/thumb-down.png" alt="Down!" name = "vote" value = "down" />
  {% else %}
    &nbsp;<input type="image" src="icons/thumb-down_gray.png" alt="Down!" name = "vote" value = "down" />
  {% endif %}
  <input type="hidden" name = "vote" value = "down"/>
  <input name= "content_key" type="hidden" value="{{ c.key.urlsafe() }}">
</form>
```

I basically doubled the code where the first part manages the upvote, and the second manages the downvote. When I click on an icon, the vote value is returned as hidden.
I think it's inevitable to double the code, otherwise you can't set a value for the hidden value according to the icon pressed.